# Is there a way to compare two objects in a List and combine their values that is most optimal?(Java)

Tags: java, compare

Quick question. Suppose I have a function total (List list) and I have a MyObject class that have a String and an int displayed below and I want to compare two different object Strings in my total method. If they are the same, add the value on both of them. Otherwise, do nothing.

For example data is
{[Johanna, 200], [Jack, 205], [Johanna, 100], [Jack, 50]};

The output should look like
{[Johanna, 300], [Jack, 255]};

```
public static class MyObject {
   int value;
   String name;
   public MyObject(String nm, int val)
   {
       name = nm;
       value = val;
   }
}

public void total(List<MyObject> list) {
    List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    Collections.sort(list);
    Iterator<Order> ItrL = list.iterator();
    int index = 0;

    while(ItrL.hasNext())
    {

        MyObject compare = ItrL.next();
        Iterator<MyObject> ItrR = list.listIterator(index);
        index++;

        while (cmp.name.equals(ItrR.next().name)))
            newList.add(new MyObject(cmp.name, cmp.value + ItrR.value));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Order` in `Iterator<Order>`? Also, in which class is the `total` method as it is written after `MyObject` class is closed?

Comment: How does `Collections.sort()` work if you don't give a `compareTo` that provides total ordering???

Comment: I already have those functions even the iterator. Just figuring out is there anyway to compare two things without repeating the items that has already been called? Also i fixed the code for some incorrect names and types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method that is "most optimal" as it depends on how big the data is. The problem seems suitable for map-reduce, but if you have like only 4 elements, then the overhead cost doesn't justify a real map reduce algorithm.

So anyway, here's one alternative that is pre-Java 8 (list doesn't need to be sorted first):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> total(List<MyObject> list) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (MyObject myObject : list) {
        Integer prevValue = result.get(myObject.name);
        if (prevValue == null) {
            result.put(myObject.name, myObject.value);
        } else {
            result.put(myObject.name, myObject.value + prevValue);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do summing and comparisons in parallel with no need to sort first using streams.

```
List<MyObject> newList = Arrays.asList(
      new MyObject("Johanna", 200), 
        new MyObject("Jack", 205), 
        new MyObject("Johanna", 100),
        new MyObject("Jack", 50)
);
Map<String,Integer> map =
        newList.stream().parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mo -> mo.name, 
                Collectors.summingInt(mo -> mo.value)));
System.out.println("map = " + map);
```

Comment: I tried this, but the mo -> mo.value doesn't work as is because the compiler thinks mo is of type Object. I have to specify mo as MyObject like so: (MyObject mo) -> mo.value

Comment: It works for me as is. Java 8 does type inference so it should know that elements of a stream made from List<MyObject> are of type MyObject. Are you using my exact code including the definition of newList?

Comment: or http://ideone.com/PZNDiP - direct collector to map (`.collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.name, o -> o.value, Integer::sum))`) is a tad simpler than grouping by name and merging numbers separately. @RichN Can confirm (see http://ideone.com/zVM1sY) that code works. Old Java 8 versions / older versions of Eclipse (Luna is pretty bad with lambdas, Mars is getting there) didn't know all the type inference tricks and can cause trouble.

Comment: @zapl It was indeed on Luna, that could be the reason. I've tried the code and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce from `n^2` to `n*(n/2)` by using

```
for(int i = 0 ...
   for(int j = i + 1 ...
```

Comment: But since the list is sorted, it's O(N).

Comment: Doesn't matter if the list is sorted. And `O(n*(n/2)) = O(n^2)`. I was talking about the reduction of iterations.

Comment: You can achieve `O(n)` by converting time into space using one for loop and a map. It's propably something like `2n+kn` for reading and putting.

Comment: It's O(N) for a sorted list because there is only one loop instead of two.

Comment: You are absolutely right. If the list is sorted in that sense that objects that are equal to each other follow one another.